# Random character generator to be stored in array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, encryption

How do I instantiate my array so it has 26 random characters in it?

```
import java.util.Random; 

public class Encryption {

Random r = new Random();
char[] real = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
char[] decrypted = //??????

for( i=0; i < decrypted.length; i++) {

}
```

Comment: To instantiate an array either you need to know the size of the array or the contents of the array. `char[] decrypted = new char[26];`

Comment: is there a more conventional way of putting every letter in the alphabet in my array than what I did?

Comment: Do you need shuffled array? Or it is possible to have duplicates?

Comment: I am doing introductions to java so I am not sure what those terms mean.

Comment: so what syntax do I put in my for loop to get random characterS?

Comment: you could have a `for` loop, like `char[] real = new char[26]; for(i = 97; i <= 122 ; i++) { real[i-97] = (char)i; }`. ASCII values of a-z are 97 to 122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate the array of size 26;

```
char[] array = new char[26];
```

Add random chars (within the range of lowercase letters)

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     array[i] = (char)(r.nextInt(26) +97);
     System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```

You can modify this to create your first array by removing the random part and using `i`

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     array[i] = (char)(i + 97);
     System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: why +97? I dont understand that part

Comment: @PatGreens 97 is the decimal value of the character `a`. Look at this [ASCII character chart](http://www.asciitable.com/). So I add this so that the minimum int possible is 97 ... which is `a` when cast as a char

Comment: ooooh I see thats interesting. SOrry im fairly new to this

Comment: @PatGreens Everyone needs to start somewhere :). If you wanted uppercase Chars you add 65

Comment: What if the integer yields something like a DEL or a ~ though, is there a way to keep it where the char ASCII ends at 122?

Comment: @PatGreens In my examples, the call `r.nextInt(26)` is what controls this. The maximum number the `nextInt()` method will return is 25. Then adding 97 yeilds 122. No higher value is possible. In the second code block, it is the array length which controls this. Provided the array is no longer than 26 it won't go past 122

Answer (score 0):

To fill in your example:

```
import java.util.Random; 

public class Encryption {

  Random r = new Random();
  char[] real = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  char[] decrypted = new char[26];

  public static void main(String[] args){
    for( i=0; i < decrypted.length; i++) {
      decrypted[i] = real[r.nextInt(26)];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does this return a character

Comment: Does what return a character?

Comment: On second look, see how you call the array decrypted, I think I misunderstood what you require.  What is decrypted supposed to be? Is it the array you need to instantiate with 26 random characters in it? Presumably later you will be encrypting it with some basic shift cipher?